# Distinguish activity calling cases: from other activity/other package/by system

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I'm making a simple e-book reader app, and an activity can be called by many cases.

I'd like to distinguish callee activity to know its origin action in case of

1. From my another activity: this can be easily solved by
   `StartActivityForResult` from calling activity.
2. Called by back button click from other package app after share action ("whoops, I missed to click share button, and then back.").
3. Switched by user's multitasking choice.
4. Called by user click at the start screen: this might be known by MAIN entry point at the android manifest.

How to know above cases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea why you would need to do this but...

> 1.From my another activity: this can be easily solved by StartActivityForResult from calling activity.

Yes, as long as the calling `Activity` is your own as you can't guarantee any 3rd-party code will use `startActivityForResult(...)`. You can, however, use `getCallingPackage()` and `getCallingActivity()` in other cases.

> 2.Called by back button click from other package app after share action ("whoops, I missed to click share button, and then back.").

When the user presses the BACK button your `Activity` isn't being "called" - it's simply being resumed or re-started. The original calling app/Activity/method will still hold true - there is no way to ascertain that this has happened as the normal `Activity` life-cycle methods (`onStart()` and `onResume()`) are always called even when an `Activity` is first created.

> 3.Switched by user's multitasking choice.

If you mean using the "Recent" apps view, the same applies for my answer to 2. above.

> 4.Called by user click at the start screen: this might be known by MAIN entry point at the android manifest.

In this case `onCreate()` will be called although if your `Activity` is simply stopped for whatever reason, it may simply be restarted depending on the launch mode you use.

In short, I can't see you being able to gather much in the way of any accurate information as to how your `Activity` becomes active.

Answer (score 0):

I am not too sure about the actual way for the above question as I am too a new guy in android.
But to the best of my knowledge... called by back button and switched by user's multitasking leads the activity to enter `pause` state.

So you can access it from `"onPause"` method in your activity.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. `onPause` is a case of post loaded event, but I'd like to distinguish the cases at the `onCreate` or `onResume` moment.